# Gnus - Save several articles in a single file

Tags: gnus

I want to be able to select a number of articles and save them all in a single text file. I know about `o (gnus-summary-save-article)` and variants of this command, however as I understand it saves the *current* article.

What are my options?

Comment: Read the documentation of that function.

Comment: You just need to @Mark the articles!

Comment: Further to the comment by @politza, see the documentation of `gnus-summary-save-article` and the related `gnus-default-article-saver` for some quick pointers and customisation options. The full shebang, including how marks come into play, as @Stefan mentions, is documented at [`(gnus) Saving Articles`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Saving-Articles.html).